# Big data using Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, bigdata

I'm currently designing a solution to manage tolling transaction. Let's say we have about 2-3M transactions/day and about 1k request/s. I don't have any experience about managing that kind of "big" (in my opinion) data.

Could you guys give me any info about the capabilities of SQL Server? Can it handle that amount of data or not? Is it easy to expand the server?

If yes, please provide me some detailed articles. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Are you incapable of doing your own research?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a very good place for these kind of questions - because you are asking for opinion, rather than fact (and code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Server benchmarks and performance](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-benchmarks/industry.aspx)

[TPC-E - Top Ten Performance Results](http://www.tpc.org/tpce/results/tpce_perf_results.asp)

Lenovo System x3950 X6/Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition :

**9,145.01 tpsE** (The Performance Metric reported by TPC-E is a "business throughput” measure of the number of completed Trade-Result transactions processed per second)